# How to filter out data if "_value" is a string [Flux] [InfluxDB]

Tags: database, filter, influxdb

Among my data, there are a couple strings in the "_value" column. This means that when I use `aggregateWindow()` I get this error: `unsupported input type for mean aggregate: string`.

I want to know how I can filter out data of type string, before passing to aggregateWindow, thus avoiding the error.

Something like this maybe:

```
from(bucket: "mybucket")
  |> range(start: -10m, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => type(r["_value"]) != "string")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1m, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation, you can use [`types.isType`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/types/istype/):

> **Filter by value type**
>
> ```
> import "types"
>
> data
>     |> filter(fn: (r) => types.isType(v: r._value, type: "string"))
> ```

You may also want to consider [`types.isNumeric`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/types/isnumeric/), or - if suitable - [use regex](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/regular-expressions/#regular-expressions-in-flux).